# Prolog Duplicate element to mutliple times

Tags: prolog

My goal is to multiply the elements in my list to three times.

For example, the query is

```
?-Three([a,b,c],X).
```

Then, the expected output is

```
X = [a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c]
```

I don't know how to do that, please helps me.

Comment: What did you try? Try a simpler problem first, for example generate a list of three elements for a given element, then try to generalize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
three([],[]).
three([H|T],[H,H,H|R]):-
      three(T,R).
```